# Plugin information tabs show large blank area at top

Tags: plugins, tabs

WordPress plugin information tabs all display a large blank area at the top of the scroll box.  This occurs using Chrome, Firefox, and Edge browsers.  Scrolling down into the text box show the desired text.  Browser inspector shows these warnings:

1. Source map error: TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
   Resource URL: moz-extension://8378c19c-177d-49a5-91c5-9dc97844baec/0.js
   Source Map URL: 0.js.map
2. Source map error: TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
   Resource URL: moz-extension://8378c19c-177d-49a5-91c5-9dc97844baec/inject.js
   Source Map URL: inject.js.map
3. Source map error: TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
   Resource URL: moz-extension://8378c19c-177d-49a5-91c5-9dc97844baec/1.js
   Source Map URL: 1.js.map

How do I resolve these errors?

Comment: Those errors aren't what would be causing that issue. The issue is probably caused by another plugin. Deactivate them one by one until the issue it resolved to find the culprit.

Comment: WordPress acknowledged a known problem that causes this behavior. It will be fixed in the next point release.